# Netbeans! Components moved from design to runtime

Tags: java, netbeans

Things look one way in the design area, but are re-sizing moving around.
It does this with every LAF, its not a style issue, its creating large empty spaces where there are none on the design area.

Any ideas?
Sorry I can't post pictures, I created the profile to ask this question

What am I doing to cause this discrepancy and how can I fix it?

Comment: Best solution: Stop using netbeans generated ui code.

Comment: To add to @SamDeHaan's comment, give http://www.miglayout.com/ a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the panel layout. Right click a `jPanel -> set Layout -> grid bag` or one of the others. I've had a lot better luck with GridBag than with Free Design. Then you can go `right click-> Customize Layout` to customise

As for what you're doing on your installation that might cause this, I'm afraid I can't say.

Comment: Ok,I'll try the GridBag. I've tried the absolute and the problem got worse (with the empty space growing HUGE).